# Would AlphaZero perform better if made with transformers?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, transformer, alphazero, alphago

AlphaZero utilized a residual convolutional neural network to estimate move policy and position value.  If it was rebuilt today, would it be more efficient and powerful if they used a transformer architecture instead?  Assume the same amount of compute power and training time is available, and purely self-play, aiming for as fair a comparison as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes!

[LeelaChessZero](https://github.com/LeelaChessZero/lc0), an open-source re-implementation and continuation of AlphaZero, has been experimenting with this for a while now. Their strongest networks are currently transformers, not convolution-based ResNets anymore.

Some resources:

- The [2022 progress](https://lczero.org/blog/2023/01/2022-progress/#network-architecture) blog post
- More details on the network architecture as of 7 months ago [here](https://github.com/Ergodice/lczero-training/blob/attention-net-body/README.md)
- A [recent comparison](https://lczero.org/blog/2024/02/how-well-do-lc0-networks-compare-to-the-greatest-transformer-network-from-deepmind/) to the latest DeepMind paper, which also uses transformers.
- A [recent blog post](https://lczero.org/blog/2024/02/transformer-progress/) about the current best transformer architecture.

Comment: Cool!  Does Leela still use MCTS, in conjunction with the new transformer architecture?

Comment: Yeah they do. They've added some improvements to the core UCT formula and to the selfplay data generation process, but the big picture is still very much the same.